# Avoid to reply to an http request to save bandwidth

Tags: http, networking, nginx

I would like a server to drop the connection after having processed the request instead of replying with an http 200 to save bandwidth. I cannot change the behaviour of the http clients.

Comment: And how much bandwidth do you think you would save?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a firewall?

See [HTTP 1.1(RFC 2616)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4)

> 8.2.4 Client Behavior if Server Prematurely Closes Connection
>
> If an HTTP/1.1 client sends a request which includes a request body, but which does not include an Expect request-header field with the "100-continue" expectation, and if the client is not directly connected to an HTTP/1.1 origin server, and if the client sees the connection close before receiving any status from the server, **the client SHOULD retry the request**. If the client does retry this request, it MAY use the following "binary exponential backoff" algorithm to be assured of obtaining a reliable response...

1. Close the connection also costs a tcp message, while a 200 response without any http message body, just attaches some http headers on it.
2. It makes a potential waste of bandwidth if the client retries the request.

Comment: You are quoting an outdated document. The current recommendations are given in [RFC 7230 § 6.3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.3.1).

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov Thanks very much for your comment. I've found more info here https://evertpot.com/http-11-updated/